# Logcat de Android Studio no muestra ningún dato

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, logcat

Tengo un teléfono Vivo Y21s y me genera problema al momento de ver datos por el logcat de Android Studio.

[image: Imagen logcat]

- Tengo la aplicación seleccionada.
- Tengo nombre de paquete seleccionado.
- **Tengo** habilitado ADB.

La aplicación es lanzada correctamente pero ningún log me muestra

Estoy utilizando de esta forma el log

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Veo que el dispositivo está conectado y el proceso esta funcionando, de acuerdo a lo que comentas, el problema que presentas y que en ocasiones no permite ver los mensajes del LogCat es ocasionado generalmente por el caché, te sugiero cambiar de  "Show only selected application" a "No filters"

[image: jorgesys Android Studio LogCat 1]

al desplegarse información, cambia nuevamente a:

[image: jorgesys Android Studio LogCat 1]

Comment: La única solución que encontré fue conectarlo a ADB por medio de WIFI. Por USB siempre me muestra un par logs y después ya no. Gracias de todas formas por tu aporte

Answer (score 0):

Podria ser tambien que no tienes habilitado el debugable en el build grade ejemplo

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
     debuggable true
```

....
}
debug {
applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
debuggable true
signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
}